# Converting a string to Date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In a part of my system, I have this situation: I will receive a string that represents a date and another string that represents a time.
I need to let these informations in DateTime. So, a made it:

```
string date = "17012012";
string hour = "103445";

date = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", date.Substring(0, 2), 
            date.Substring(2, 2), date.Substring(4, 4));
hour = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", hour.Substring(0, 2),
            hour.Substring(2, 2), hour.Substring(4, 2));

DateTime example = new DateTime();
example = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", date, hour));
```

Ok, but is it a good pattern? Are there a "more beautiful" way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) instead

e.g.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date + hour, "ddMMyyyyHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) and [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) DateTime methods in the MSDN documentation.

I think that also [Parsing Dates and Times in .NET](http://blog.stevex.net/parsing-dates-and-times-in-net/) can help.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another your program must parse this format.
I would have done like this:

```
string date = "17012012";
string time = "103445";

int year = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(4, 4));
int month = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(2, 2));
int day = Convert.ToInt32(date.Substring(0, 2));
int hour = Convert.ToInt32(time.Substring(0, 2));
int minute = Convert.ToInt32(time.Substring(2, 2));
int second = Convert.ToInt32(time.Substring(4, 2));

DateTime example = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
```

Comment: Yes, also. But I used DateTime.ParseExact, it's a elegant way. Thanks!